# The setOptions() does not work on a chart in a ChartWrapper after I run the ChartEditor

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a chart in a wrapper:

```
var wrapper9 = null;
var chartcolors09 = parent.defaultcolors;
var chartEditor9 =null;

    function Chart9() {


       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTableB9?>);

      wrapper9 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType:'BarChart',
         dataTable: data,
          options: {
              'colors': chartcolors09,

       'chartArea': {
              'left': 40,
              'top': 50,
              'right': 100,
              'bottom': 50
            },
         'legend' :'Right',

         'title':'Chart Title'
         }   

      });   
}
```

I can run a function to update colors of that chart using this function:

```
   function setcolor9(){

        wrapper9.setOptions({

  'colors': chartcolors09
});
        wrapper9.draw(document.getElementById('chart_div9'));

      }
```

and this works just fine. I can also use other functions on that chartin that wrapper to update some other options. BUT when I use the ChartEditor on this chart

```
function loadEditor9() {

        chartEditor9 = new google.visualization.ChartEditor();
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chartEditor9, 'ok', redrawChart9);

      chartEditor9.openDialog(wrapper9, {});    
}

    function redrawChart9(){ 
         chartEditor9.getChartWrapper().draw(document.getElementById('chart_div9'));
    }
```

the setcolor9() function stops working. It kinda looks like the ChartEditor created a 2nd chart and put it on top of the first one and the setcolor9() function keeps referring to the first one.
...oh and not sure if this is connected but the chart created by the loadEditor9() and redrawChart9() functions seems to ignore the height and width options set by other functions in the wrapper9 var and goes "outside" of the div container.

Comment: From what I understand from the official documentation 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#example
chartWrapper and chartEditor are 2 different classes and in my case I think I should use the setChartWrapper() function, but Cannot figure out how to use it. @PaulH sorry to bother you but could you in a spare minute take a look at this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is of course very simple.

I just needed to change the redrawChart9() function to the below and now I can do whatever I want with that chart.

```
function redrawChart9(){

      wrapper9 = chartEditor9.getChartWrapper();
      wrapper9.draw();

    }
```